# Implementing an interface in ThisOutlookSession is not working in Office 2013

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook macro I wrote that will automatically mark items as read when I move them to a folder. (I hate having unread messages in folders other than my Inbox.) I wrote the macro in Outlook 2010, and it's been functioning well for years.

I recently upgraded to Office 2013, and now my macro doesn't work--I'm getting a type mismatch error on this line (see below for the full code):

```
Set oMoveHandler.Callback = Me
```

oMoveHandler.Callback expects an object of type IMessageMoved, which the object implements, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

ThisOutlookSession code:

```
Option Explicit

Implements IMessageMoved

Private m_oFolderCollection As Collection

Private Sub Application_Quit()
    Set m_oFolderCollection = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder

    Set m_oFolderCollection = New Collection
    For Each oFolder In Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders
        Call AddFolder(oFolder)
    Next oFolder
End Sub

Private Sub AddFolder(Folder As Outlook.Folder)
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oMoveHandler As MoveHandler

    If Folder Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Folder.Folders.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each oFolder In Folder.Folders
        If oFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
            If oFolder.Name <> "Inbox" And oFolder.Name <> "Outbox" And oFolder.Name <> "ePrescribing Workgroup" Then
                Set oMoveHandler = New MoveHandler
                Set oMoveHandler.Folder = oFolder.Items
                Set oMoveHandler.Callback = Me
                Call m_oFolderCollection.Add(oMoveHandler)
                Set oMoveHandler = Nothing
            End If
            Call AddFolder(oFolder)
        End If
    Next oFolder
End Sub

Private Function IMessageMoved_MessageMoved(Item As Object) As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    Item.UnRead = False
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

IMessageMoved:

```
Public Function MessageMoved(Item As Object)
End Function
```

MoveHandler:

```
Private WithEvents m_oFolder As Outlook.Items
Private m_oCallback As IMessageMoved

Public Property Set Folder(Folder As Outlook.Items)
    Set m_oFolder = Folder
End Property

Public Property Get Folder() As Outlook.Items
    Set Folder = m_oFolder
End Property

Public Property Set Callback(Object As IMessageMoved)
    Set m_oCallback = Object
End Property

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_oFolder = Nothing
    Set m_oCallback = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub m_oFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If Not m_oCallback Is Nothing Then
        Call m_oCallback.MessageMoved(Item)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect I was actually running into a similar issue to the one described [in this post describing a similar problem in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699566/how-can-i-cast-a-worksheet-that-implements-and-interface-into-an-object-of-the-t) where binding just wasn't working as expected. To work around it, I ended up moving my interface out of ThisOutlookSession into a separate class which I then just instantiate from ThisOutlookSession.