# TypeOf fails to work with Excel workbook's ActiveSheet that implements interface

Tags: excel, vba, class, interface, polymorphism

I have a *PublicNotCreatable* interface `PublicInterface`

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoSomething()
End Sub
```

And in the *same* workbook, I have a single sheet, `Sheet1`, that *implements* `PublicInterface`

```
Option Explicit

Implements PublicInterface

Private Sub PublicInterface_DoSomething()
  Beep
End Sub
```

Then, in `Module1`, I have code that tries to determine whether `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` is of type `PublicInterface`

```
Sub testSheet()

  Dim sht As Object
  For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    'DOES run
    Debug.Print "Enumerated Sheet Is PublicInterface"
  Next sht

  If TypeOf ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet Is PublicInterface Then
    '*** Doesn't run ***
    Debug.Print "ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet Is PublicInterface"
  End If

  Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
  If TypeOf ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet Is PublicInterface Then
    'DOES run
    Debug.Print "After getting an ActiveSheet property, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet Is PublicInterface"
  End If

  If TypeOf ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name) Is PublicInterface Then
    'DOES Run
    Debug.Print "ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name) Is PublicInterface"
  End If

  If TypeOf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name) Is PublicInterface Then
    'DOES Run
    Debug.Print "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name) Is PublicInterface"
  End If

  'Force the project to reset
  End

End Sub
```

It seems that `TypeOf ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet Is PublicInterface` returns `False` if the project has been reset, but if you remove the `End` statement (so the project doesn't reset), and run the code twice, it returns `False` the first time, and `True` thereafter (and until the project is reset), because subsequent lines of code seem to *force* the resolution of the sheet's type. Likewise, if you step though the code, it returns `True` *every* time.

Interestingly, `TypeOf Sheet1 Is PublicInterface` seems to work. Also, the same problem is *not* evident when implementing the interface on `ThisWorkbook`, and using `TypeOf ThisWorkbook Is PublicInterface` does return `True`

This smells like a VBA bug. I *suspect* it has to do with compilation timing of the worksheet. Is this a known issue? Am I doing something wrong in checking `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet`? I couldn't seem to reproduce this behavior with regular classes whether `Private` or `PublicNotCreatable`.

If I need to check whether the workbook's ActiveSheet implements an interface, is this likely to be the safest approach:

`If TypeOf ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name) Is PublicInterface Then`

Comment: Do I read this properly as yet another reason to avoid working with  `ActiveSheet`?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes, quite possibly. I'm *hoping* this is isolated to `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` (or `workbookReference.ActiveSheet`) and not something that might manifest itself in other classes (given the right conditions/attributes). But I've just tested, and it seems to apply to `ActiveChart` also.

Comment: Interesting. The ActiveSheet property has a weird behavior, I think because it is somehow "overloaded", it could be a `Chart`, a `Worksheet`, a `Sheet1` or so... It should be declared as an `Object` and has some special mechanisms to extend its (IDispatch?) interface at run-time. Notice that it never offers any intellisense in the editor.

Comment: @A.S.H yes, `ActiveSheet` returns an `Object`, but the same behavior occurs with `ActiveChart` which returns a `Chart`. I *suspect* it is because implementing an interface on `Sheet1` or `Chart` is *extending* `Sheet1`/`Chart1`, but `Sheet1` is *already* extending `Worksheet` (and `Chart1` is *already* extending `Chart`).

Comment: Found a similar post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500674/why-would-vba-typeof-operator-fail-in-excel

Comment: How *"extending"* works in VBA is the big puzzle. For instance, if you type `?typename(Sheet1)` you get `"Worksheet"`. But since the `Sheet1 class` extends `Worksheet` you would expect that it returns `"Sheet1"` (the most specialized class). Why this happens is beyond me, but I consider it as against the principle, and the class hierarchy model is a little messy.

Comment: @A.S.H Yes, that... And the Locals window can't even display the properties of an interface http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146243/how-to-get-property-values-of-classes-that-implement-an-interface-in-the-locals Any wonder most VBA devs have never used `Implements`

Comment: Just for the records. This behaviour doesn't happen if you set the active sheet through ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Comment: So a workaround for this could be to execute ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Activate before doing the test.

Comment: This kind of test has always confused me in any language - because an interface isn't a class or an object per se, it can't possibly know what type will be implementing it (and it doesn't care either, so long as it's implemented properly). So I would never expect something like `TypeOf` to return true when comparing an object to an interface? An interface can also be implemented by a class at any given level of heirarchy - so it intrinsically doesn't follow a chain and therefore makes it harder to test for `Type` comparisons.